# Crashes for no reason

Tags: crash

Ubuntu is crashing for no reason. It keeps on flashing every 5 or maybe 7 seconds until it crashes.

[image: es]

Comment: Why would Ubuntu crash if there is no reason? Your statement appears to be wrong. What is your question? I don't see a question here. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1495267/edit) your post to clarify and please, also add details about your Ubuntu version and your hardware. Thank you.